# Subscript out of bounds error in caret's rfe function

Tags: r, r-caret, rfe

I am trying to use Caret's rfe function to do feature selection.  My code worked not even a few days ago. Now I am getting a subscript of of bounds error. The weird part is I can run the rfe function with some built in data from another package no problem, which to me means that this is likely an issue with my data (but I can't figure out what).  Any suggestions??

### WORKS

load the library

```
library(mlbench)
library(caret)
library(randomForest)
```

load the data

```
data(PimaIndiansDiabetes)
```

define the control using a random forest selection function

```
control <- rfeControl(functions=rfFuncs2, method="cv", number=10)
```

run the RFE algorithm

```
results <- rfe(PimaIndiansDiabetes[,1:8], PimaIndiansDiabetes[,9], sizes=c(1:8), rfeControl=control)
```

### DOESN'T WORK

```
results<-rfe(stores[,10:33], stores[,8],sizes=c(1:24), rfeControl=control)
```

My dataframe "stores" is a bunch of continuous variables (10:33), and a grouping variable (8)

Any Thoughts?

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Hi, please define rfFuncs2, it will help to replicate your exact same result

Answer (score 2):

I meet the same problem, you can try `as.factor(unlist(stores[,8]))`

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that your 'y' variable (e.g., stores[,8]) is coded as a character not a factor variable. Use the following snippet to change your character to factor and RFE will run: stores[,8] <- as.factor(stores[,8])

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).